# Xcode, how do I rename entirely a project ?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I have renamed an Xcode project but it's "build name" ("Scene Kit Session...") hasn't changed :
[image]
Do you know how to change it to "TPE" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on build name and go to **manage schemes**

[image]

The following window will appear

[image]

Slowly click twice on the scheme "build name" it will be become editable then change the name and click at anywhere in the empty space of this window then click **OK** the name will be changed

Answer (score 1):

That is the name of the "Scheme" (which is not renamed automatically when the target
is renamed).

In the Xcode menu, goto **Project->Scheme...->Manage Schemes**, click on the scheme name
and rename it.

Alternatively, if you did not make any custom settings to the scheme, you can delete
the scheme and click on the "Autocreate Schemes Now" button. This will create a scheme
for each target with the same name as the target.

And be sure to make a backup before such modifications to your project!